# A few questions about "particularly"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, idiomatic-language

> I don't want to talk about it. I doubt you'd find it
> particularly interesting to hear about, either.

I have a few questions about "particularly":

- Would "particularly" sound perfectly natural here, more than "especially" and "specially"?
- Is it equally natural in BrE and AmE?
- Is it formal, informal, or in between?

Comment: particularly is the same in all varieties of English. You can check these uses (mostly) in the online Collins Dictionary.

Comment: It's an ***intensifier*** - very often used in *negating* contexts such as yours *("You **won't** find it particularly interesting")*, but also used as a positive intensifier - *She plays the piano **particularly** well*. It's neither formal nor informal - it's just "language".